# How to globally limit total number of TCP connections with iptables?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, tcp, tcpip

I'm having quite a difficult time figuring out how to REJECT both inbound *and* outbound connections from a machine with iptables once the total number of TCP connections hits a global maximum without respect to source or destination port.  All sources/destinations/ports must be included.

Is this possible with iptables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m connlimit --connlimit-above <your limit number> --connlimit-mask 0 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --syn -m connlimit --connlimit-above <your limit number> --connlimit-mask 0 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thank you! I may have an opportunity to test this tonight and if it works well, I'll accept the answer! :)

Comment: Works a treat, and (as should be obvious from the above) with iptables you can limit the total number of connections allowed in ANY chain, including input, output, and custom ones.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it using iptables module "connlimit"

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport $port -m connlimit --connlimit-above N -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

example:

```
/sbin/iptables  -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 3 -j REJECT
```

Comment: I'm looking for an absolute global limit, though, for the entire machine - not just a single port.

Comment: `--reject-with` is only port 113 I guess? Also it's probably best [not to reject](https://man.archlinux.org/man/iptables-extensions.8.en#REJECT_(IPv4-specific)) INVALID packets?

Comment: By the way, doesn't your answer lack `--connlimit-mask 0` to limit the total number of connections?